# How to get Email from SiteUsers using filter dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to fetch the User details from SiteUsers Rest API using Email on the basis of filter. Value passed in email would be dynamic value coming from another API and value of email will be in LowerCase and Email value from Data coming from SiteUsers will be in the form of both uppercase and lowercase. So we should apply filters so that we can match both the values coming from the Data and from the dynamic value as well. Filter is case sensitive in Rest API. What will be the exact API for filtering Email so that we can get the filtered data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Rest API, filter is case sensitive when filtering site users based on email.

A workaround is use ListData.svc to filter UserInformation List, this way will ignore case sensitive:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=WorkEmail eq 'mailstodl1@zheguo.onmicrosoft.com'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it works

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Glad to hear it's working for you. You can accept this reply as answer.

Comment: @GauravKumar, could you please Accept the reply as answer to close this case ? Thanks :)